# ¿donde conseguir glut para dev-c++?

Tags: c++, api, windows, dev-c++, opengl

Últimamente he estado aprendiendo c++ con el editor de código dev-c++
llevo bastante tiempo aprendiendo y decidí por fin dar el gran paso al mundo grafico(opengl).

Empecé a buscar tutoriales en internet y siempre utilizaban glut.h que es como una extensión o algo así para simplificar el trabajo.

Cuando importaba esa libreria en el ordenador me daba error,Luego me di cuenta que servia como sustituto para la API de windows que es `<windows.h>`.

Mire muchos tutoriales y ninguno funcionaba los seguía al pie de la letra y siempre fallaban. Cada vez que trataba de conseguirlo siempre ocurría un desastre que incluso me llevo una vez a desinstalar dev-c++ para volver lo a instalar.

**EN RESUMEN**

1-Me pueden dar un link de descarga para poder descargar glut.Y que ustedes hayan utilizado ese link en su momento.

2-Y si no, me pueden enseñar un link de algún tutorial que use la API de windows y opengl sin usar glut. O sea que solo tenga que incluir librerías que vengan con dev-c++.

**Por favor** he buscado mucho y no he encontrado se los pido por favor que me ayuden.

Gracias... de todas formas Feliz año nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

No vas a encontrar una versión de glut para dev-cpp **porque no existe** tal cosa. dev-cpp es un IDE o entorno de desarrollo integrado, es decir, es una especie de editor de código al que se le han añadido varias opciones adicionales, como poder compilar y depurar desde el propio editor.

En un IDE, las tareas de compilación y depuración son realizadas por programas externos. Por este motivo no vas a encontrar una librería para dev-cpp. Lo que tienes que hacer, en este caso, es buscar librerías para **windows**.

Así, lo normal es que acabes llegando a la página oficial de [opengl](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php) y de ahí a una página de [ibiblio.org](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/packages/development/graphics/glut/). Esta última página contiene varios enlaces ... el que te interesa es el último [glutdlls.zip](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/packages/development/graphics/glut/glutdlls.zip)

Answer (score 0):

De mí experiencia con OpenGL, conozco algunas alternativas.

Librerías para cargar las funciones de OpenGL:

- [GLEW](https://glew.sourceforge.net/) lleva más tiempo con nosotros.
- [GLAD](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) relativamente nueva.

Para la creación de ventanas:

- Forma nativa, depende del sistema operativo
- GLUT (descontinuado), fue una de las primeras librerías.
- [FREEGLUT](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut), de código abierto y sugerida por [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/).
- [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/), solo permite la creación de ventanas, el uso de mouse, teclado y otros controles.
- [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) y [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) permiten la creación de ventanas, uso de mouse, teclado, otros controles y audio.

En internet puedes encontrar tutoriales sobre cómo usar y compilar estas librerías desde su código fuente para usarlas en dev-c++.

En cuanto a OpenGL, sugiero que aprendas OpenGL moderno. Es un poco más difícil pero te permite hacer gráficos más eficientes. Un buen sitio es [learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/).